# How can i search all github repositories by file extension using github API

Tags: github, github-api

I want to search all repositories that contain the extension *.xcodeproj
When i query at my browser: `https://github.com/search?q=extension%3Axcodeproj+language%3ASwift&type=repositories`, it returns: 427,768 results.

But when I query the same using github API, query: `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=extension:xcodeproj+language:Swift`, it returns 0 results.

I also tried: `https://api.github.com/search/code?q=extension:xcodeproj+language:Swift`, still same result.

Not sure what's going wrong there.
Edit: Yes I am using the PAT token to bypass the rate limit and code search (without repo+org+owner) constraint.

Answer (score 1):

The Github API query should be the following. You need to use `&` to add search criteria.

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=extension:xcodeproj&language:Swift
```